# An extra backslash character do not effect my program. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, backslash

This code will work and run fine with g++.
I do not no why. It should give an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x=9;
    int y=6;
    //note that there is extra backslash in the end of if statement
    if(x==y)\
    {
        cout<<"x=y"<<endl;
    }
    //note that there is extra backslash in the end of if statement
    if(x!=y)\
    {
        cout<<"x!=y"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you feel that it should fail to compile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the C++ Standard:

> (C++11, 2.2p1) "Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice."

C says exactly the same:

> (C11, 5.1.1.2 Translatation phases p1) "Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical
>   source lines to form logical source lines."

So:

```
if(x==y)\
{
    cout<<"x=y"<<endl;
}
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
if(x==y){
    cout<<"x=y"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I did the following:

if(x==y)\ //this is some words
{
    cout<<"x=y"<<endl;
}
I should be equivalent to this
if(x==y)\ //this is some words{
    cout<<"x=y"<<endl;
}
It is still work

Comment: @user1061392 What compiler are you using? g++ [doesn't compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e5c1e0259897a999853bc8e6c3302668) the code if you put a comment after the backslash.

Comment: It should not compile as comments are treated in translation phase 3 and the final backslash character is treated before, in translation phase 2.

Answer (score 6):

`\` escapes the newline. `g++` will read `if(x==y){` on one line, which is not a syntax error.